# Injectivity and Surjectivity of two different functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

a) If there is a function f: A-->B where there are two distinct elements a, b that are in A such that f(a) ≠ f(b), does this make f injective?

I think the answer is true because if a and b don't equal each other, then f(a) ≠ f(b).

b) If there is a function g: A-->B where for every b in B, there are two distinct elements a1, a2 in A such that f(a1) = b and f(a2) = b. Is f surjective?

I also think this is true, but am not quite sure.

Comment: Wikipedia has nice answers:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function
for injectivity and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function
for surjective functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a) you are only told that $f(a) \neq f(b)$ for some particular points $a$ and $b$. This does not imply that $f$ is injective. For example let $f(x)=x^{2}$ from $\mathbb R$ into itself. Take $a=1$ and $b=2$. Then $f(a) \neq f(b)$. But $f$ is not injective because $f(-1)=f(1)$.

For b) the answer is YES, since there is $a_1$ is one point where the value $b$ is attained.

Answer (score 0):

For part a, having a pair of values $x_1$, $x_2$ in the domain such that $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$ is definitely not sufficient to prove injectivity. In order to prove that $f$ is an injection it is necessary to show that if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ then $x_1 = x_2$ for all $x$ in the domain.

For part b, no matter how many values in the domain map to a given value in the codomain, $f$ is surjective if for any element $y$ of the codomain, there exists an element in the domain, $x$, such that $f(x) = y$. How many such values there are doesn't matter for surjectivity, so long as there is at least one.